# Angular 2: Http Response Status Codes as constants

Tags: angular

Does Angular 2 framework contain **Http Response Status Codes as constants**?

So instead of writing **404** I can write **HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND**.

Thanks!

Comment: you can make use of a properties  file which contains all of your response codes and then import that file in services and use

Comment: I agree with @RahulSingh. Responses only contain the error code number, but not a specific string code.

Comment: Does this exist? It does in Java. I found this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-status-codes) but I would love to know if it exists in the angular framework itself.

Comment: You can define your Enum or you can use http-status-codes module 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-status-codes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

as of now in angular 12 this feature is now available

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpStatusCode

Comment: Unluckily it's a 'const enum', meaning it cannot be used at runtime to transform a http status code (e.g 401) to its corresponding text (Unauthorized) (here is the code: https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/6fe3a1d)

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately at this point in time there doesn't seem to be an enum or const for the exact error codes.

You'd be better off doing something like @Jeff suggested, by using a library like the [http-status-codes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-status-codes) which has them all listed and documented.

Angular's [Response class](https://angular.io/api/http/Response) allows you to check if a request was successful by means of the 'ok' property (boolean), otherwise you can access the status code/text from that object.

Comment: http-status-code library is very small and useful even in Angular 5.

Comment: It's not a bad library at all. With a majority of the instances the basic Angular Response class variables should be ok, but in the instance that you want to do checks for specific responses and have it done in a clean way,  http-status-codes is the way to go